# How do I output var f?

Tags: javascript, typescript, output

I have a button that runs a specific function when it is clicked.  The issue now is I can't seem to get that specific value to display on the html page once click. How do you output var f so that it'll show on the html page and not just in the console?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>

    

    
        function get() {
    
          var tinput: HTMLInputElement = < HTMLInputElement > document.getElementById('total');
    
          var t: number = parseFloat(tinput.value);
    
          var f: number = t * .45;
    <!-- rounds var f to just two decimal places -->

          var f: number = Math.round(f * 100) / 100
    
    <!-- logs to the console-->

          console.log(f);
    
        }
    
    
    
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
    
        <head>
          <title></title>
        </head>
    
        <body>
    
          <div id="output">
            <input id="total" />

            <input value="click" onclick="get()" type="button" />
          </div>
    
    
    
          <script src="src/main.js"></script>
        </body>
    
        </html>
    
    




    </title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="output">
                <input id="total" />

                <input value="click"  onclick="getTip()" type="button" />
            </div>
            <script src="src/main.js"></script>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: `< HTMLInputElement >` is a syntax error. Please fix that first.

Comment: there are no strict types in JS...

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 0):

To show it in the page instead of the console, use:

```
document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = f;
```

Comment: I can't add f because typescript is reading it as a string when it's actually a number

Comment: I don't know Typescript. Javascript automatically converts numbers to strings when necessary.

Comment: If Typescript won't let you assign like this, I assume it has a function to convert numbers to strings. Call that function when doing the assignment.

Comment: As a note, any type can always be cast to any other. If str is a string, this is valid TypeScript:

var n: number = <number><any>str;

I didn't say it was beautiful TypeScript, but there will be occaisons like these where you know more than the compiler. In this case, it is because you are trying to make use of primitive type coercion, which generally leads to brittle code and is not enforced by the TypeScript compiler.